# How to extend Java String Pool size (JDK 1.6)?

Tags: java

I'm forced to use JDK 1.6 for some reasons and i know that JDK 1.6 String pool size is limited to 512 MB so using 1.8 is solution but i can't use JDK 1.8.
So please let me know how to extend String pool Size.

Answer (score 1):

The internalization of string in java 1.6 is in the permegen area so a:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1G
```

should do the trick

[Source](http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/)

Comment: I mean my server (where jdk 1.6 is installed) goes down once string pool is full. there are number of users and lots of instances are created by each. So any Solution?

Comment: you have to increase the permgen where the string internalization pool is stored once done, if you resized the permgen correctly the jvm shouldn't crash anymore just start the jvm with a reasonable permgen size

Comment: Okk, Sounds good. Can you please let me know how to increase permgen space ??